# vsts extension Git Rest Client unauthorized

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, pull-request

I try to create an Azure DevOps extension getting the current pull request. But I'm face to an unauthorized exception :
[image]

I checked the token sent in the request, it's the same I get with :

```js
VSS.getAccessToken().then(function(token) {
    var authHeader = VSS_Auth_Service.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);
    console.log(authHeader);
});
```

The git client is instantiated like this :

```js
VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient"], function (VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
    // Get the REST client
    var gitClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.GitHttpClient2_2);

    gitClient.getPullRequest(tabContext.repositoryId, tabContext.pullRequestId)
             .thenResolve(pr => {
                console.log(pr);
             });
    });
```

I tried also this way :

```js
VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/VersionControl/GitRestClient"], function (VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
    // Get the REST client
    var gitClient = TFS_Wit_WebApi.getClient();

    gitClient.getPullRequest(tabContext.repositoryId, tabContext.pullRequestId)
             .thenResolve(pr => {
                console.log(pr);
             });
    });
```

The extension manifest is :

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "complete-pr-extension",
    "publisher": "aguafrommars",
    "version": "1.0.8",
    "name": "Complete Pull Request",
    "description": "Complete a Pull Request with commity zen",
    "public": false,
    "categories": ["Code"],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "pull-request-details-tab",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.tab",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-code-web.pr-tabs"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Complete Pull Request",
                "title": "Complete Pull Request",
                "uri": "complete-pr.html",
                "action": "PR Details Tab"
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "complete-pr.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib",
            "addressable": true,
            "packagePath": "lib"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I install the extension to my local TFS 2018 Update 2 using :

```sh
tfx extension publish --service-url http://localhost:8080/tfs --token {my-token} --rev-version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found where was my issue, I missed to add the scope in my manifest :

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
...
    "scopes": [
        "vso.code_full"
    ],
...
}
```

You can find all available scopes in [Extension manifest reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/manifest?view=azure-devops#scopes)